# C# how to get array elements in another class

Tags: c#, oop

I have two pages, on the first page I decode a file from which I get the coordinates and write them to an array. I want to use this array in another class.

```
public sealed partial class FileManagerPage : Page
{
    public float[] arr;
    public struct _arrayByte...
    static int Decode_dy(byte b0, byte b1, byte b2)...
    static int Decode_dx(byte b0, byte b1, byte b2)...
    private async void FileList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _arrayByte _bytes;
        StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
        StorageFolder usbStorage = externalDrives[0];
        StorageFile file1 = await usbStorage.GetFileAsync(fileList.SelectedItem.ToString());
        if (file1 != null)
        {
            var buffer1 = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file1);
            byte[] buf1 = WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(buffer1);
            int FileLenght = ((((buf1.Length - header) / 3) * 3) + header);
            MassLenght_x_y = ((FileLenght - header) / 3) * sizeof(int) * 2;
            int dx,dy,k = 0;
            float ix,iy = 0;
            int[] a = new int[MassLenght_x_y];
            arr = new float[MassLenght_x_y];
            MassLenght_x_y = ((FileLenght - header) / 3) * sizeof(int) * 2;
            if (MassLenght_x_y > 0) Array.Clear(a, 0, a.Length); //Очистить массив
            for (int i = header; i < FileLenght; i += 3, k += 2)
            {
                _bytes.b0 = buf1[i];
                _bytes.b1 = buf1[i + 1];
                _bytes.b2 = buf1[i + 2];
                dx = Decode_dx(_bytes.b0, _bytes.b1, _bytes.b2);
                dy = Decode_dy(_bytes.b0, _bytes.b1, _bytes.b2);
                a[k] = dx; 
                a[k + 1] = dy;
                ix = ix + dx;
                iy = iy + (-1 * dy);
                arr[k] = ix;
                arr[k + 1] = iy;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to read an array "arr" in another class

```
public sealed partial class Win2DPage : Page
{
    ...
    private void CanvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!Window.Current.Visible) return;
        float x0, y0, x1, y1;
        for (int a = 0; a < MassLenght_x_y; a += 4)
        {
            if (a >= 4)
            {
                a = a - 2;
                x0 = 300f + 0.3f * arr[a]; //error
                y0 = 300f + 0.3f * arr[a + 1];
                x1 = 300f + 0.3f * arr[a + 2];
                y1 = 300f + 0.3f * arr[a + 3];
                args.DrawingSession.DrawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, Colors.Red);
            }
            else
            {
                x0 = 300f + 0.3f * arr[a]; //error
                y0 = 300f + 0.3f * arr[a + 1];
                x1 = 300f + 0.3f * arr[a + 2];
                y1 = 300f + 0.3f * arr[a + 3];
                args.DrawingSession.DrawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, Colors.Red);
            }
        }
        CanvasControl.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I think this is a very stupid question, but I still could not find the answer...
[Found such examples](http://www.functionx.com/csharp3/Lesson22.htm) But I think they do not fit me, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Why are you not simply passing it as a function argument to the class that you need it ? Create a property in your main class that has arr to expose it and just pass it to CanvasControl_Draw or make your FileManagerPage  object as accessible to this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your working on web form, If you want to pass data from one web page to another web page in asp webform, you can use one of this ways:

1. Cookies
2. QueryString
3. Sessions
4. Cross-Page Posting
5. Server.Transfer

for your scenario I think that sessions is best choose, because your array may have a big size sending it to client and receiving on server side will have a bad performance on page size and loading

EDIT
if you work on UWP, so you should pass data when call navigate method, for example we create a param class:

```
public class MyParams
{
public MyParams(){}
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

so when we want to navigate another page, first create a object from MyParams class and pass in navigate method:

```
var param = new MyParams(){
    Name = "Mostafa"
}
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Win2DPage), param);
```

and now you can read param values in Win2DPage, just you need to override OnNavigatedTo method as below:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
var parameters = (MyParams)e.Parameter;
// parameters.Name    
}
```

Comment: This is not a web form. This is UWP

Comment: @ErgoStrife I edited my answer for both webform and UWP

Answer (score 0):

You could use your array as a static variable and write this coordinates to the static array. Later, when you read it in another class you just call

```
FirstPageClass.YourStaticVariable
```

and you'll have your values.
But if you do this way, make sure to check if the values were already read and set to this variable.

Comment: Static state is a seductive mistress that will lure you down a very dark path.